# Magento 2 : Get invalidated cache types

Tags: magento2, cache

I am creating a module that clears invalidated cache,

I am trying to get invalidated cache types in controller, so i can clear cache for only cache types which are invalidated.

How to invalidated cache types in controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out how Magento does it when rendering the caches in `vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Cache/Grid/Column/Statuses.php`.

Basically, it injects the `\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface` class in constructor and it retrieves the list of invalidated caches by calling the method of the concrete class `vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/TypeList.php` which implements the method:

```php
$this->_cacheTypeList->getInvalidated()
```

Comment: i am assuming, that using this class & calling this getInvalidated method i will get the invalidated cache types in controller.

Comment: yes, that's right. you should get the right results. I just edited my answer and added the concrete class reference also.

Comment: $output = [];
        foreach ($this->_cacheTypeList->getInvalidated() as $type) {
            $output[] = $type->getCacheType();
        }
        return $output;

Comment: Thankyou for the answer

Comment: you're welcome! consider marking the answer as solution so others can see it too. cheers!